# How do I view my Apache log nicely? (I don't want to "analyze" it)

Tags: administrator, logging, website

I tried [Webalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webalizer) but it turned out I actually want something different.

- I don't need percentages or "top 10" lists
- I want a full list of unique IPs
- and a way to see all pages/files someone visited (this doesn't include files they downloaded by visiting a page that referenced them).
- For each IP I want to see the browser, OS, referrer and country (or if possible, more specific geographic info).
- I want it all broken down into sections of the site. For example I want to view info for `/blog/*` seperately from info about `/forum/*`
- It would be nice if the info page is simply generated when requested from the browser, rather than having to make a cron job for it.

All of this is just out of curiosity who visits my site.

[captcha: "great nicotine". D'oh! :)]

Comment: The mean answer: learn a scripting language! We just did basically a subset of your requirements in a Perl assignment at school. I can hook you up with some of my code if you'd like. We're doing the Geolocation stuff in the next assignment :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) then.

> **A full log analysis enables AWStats to
>   show you the following information:**
>
> - Number of visits, and number of unique visitors,
> - Visits duration and last visits,
> - Authenticated users, and last authenticated visits,
> - Days of week and rush hours (pages, hits, KB for each hour and day of
>     week),
> - Domains/countries of hosts visitors (pages, hits, KB, 269
>     domains/countries detected, GeoIp
>     detection),
> - Hosts list, last visits and unresolved IP addresses list,
> - Most viewed, entry and exit pages,
> - Files type,
> - Web compression statistics (for mod_gzip or mod_deflate),
> - OS used (pages, hits, KB for each OS, 35 OS detected),
> - Browsers used (pages, hits, KB for each browser, each version (Web, Wap,
>     Media browsers: 97 browsers, more than
>     450 if using browsers_phone.pm library
>     file),
> - Visits of robots (319 robots detected),
> - Worms attacks (5 worm's families),
> - Search engines, keyphrases and keywords used to find your site (The
>     115 most famous search engines are
>     detected like yahoo, google,
>     altavista, etc...),
> - HTTP errors (Page Not Found with last referrer, ...),
> - Other personalized reports based on url, url parameters, referer field for
>     miscellanous/marketing purpose,
> - Number of times your site is "added to favourites bookmarks".
> - Screen size (need to add some HTML tags in index page).
> - Ratio of Browsers with support of: Java, Flash, RealG2 reader, Quicktime
>     reader, WMA reader, PDF reader (need
>     to add some HTML tags in index page).
> - Cluster report for load balanced servers ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Apache Log Viewer. It's a free tool where the apache log file is color coded according to the status code. There is also a filter facility. You can even generate some reports to view the data in a different format.

http://www.apacheviewer.com

Comment: this is not exactly free; it's mostly-free-with-unlockable-features.  donate to get the unlock code to access the features.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [goaccess](https://goaccess.io/) - which is an open-source tool that provides both terminal and HTML based reporting (as mentioned [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/35248)). With the `-a` option it provides a per-host agent listing, and includes geoip data etc. It can also provide for real-time report generation. For example to run it in the terminal (`-c`: asks you to choose your config on startup):

```
goaccess -c -a -f path_to_your_logfile
```

[image]